# Django throws too many values to unpack (expected 2) when I return a render

Tags: python, django, django-views

When I return a render from a function-based view in Django, it is giving the error:

too many values to unpack (expected 2).

I am giving the render 3 values (request, template_name, context), but the docs say it should be ok, and it has worked elswhere.

Here is my code:

View:

```
@login_required
def updateview(request, pk):
if request.method == "POST":
    instance = get_object_or_404(Listing, tag=pk)
    updateform = ListingUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
    if updateform.is_valid():
        updateform.save()
        listing = updateform.instance
        messages.success(request, "New Listing Created")
        return redirect(reverse('main:listingdetails', kwargs={'pk': listing.tag}))
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')

updateform = ListingUpdateForm
return render(request,
            "main/createlisting.html",
            context={"updateform":updateform})
```

Template:

```
{% block content %}

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{updateform}}

    <button type="submit">post</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Form:

```
class ListingUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
countryList = (("US", "United States"),
    ("UK", "United Kingdom")),

country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=countryList)

class Meta:
    model = Listing
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'price', 'country')
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\-\Downloads\zephyrus\main\views.py", line 102, in createview
    return render(request,

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 53, in render
    result = self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 973, in render_value_in_context
    value = str(value)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 376, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 132, in __str__
    return self.as_table()

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 270, in as_table
    return self._html_output(

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 227, in _html_output
    output.append(normal_row % {

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 376, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 34, in __str__
    return self.as_widget()

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 93, in as_widget
    return widget.render(

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 246, in render
    context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 683, in get_context
    context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 644, in get_context
    context['widget']['optgroups'] = self.optgroups(name, context['widget']['value'], attrs)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 607, in optgroups
    for subvalue, sublabel in choices:

Exception Type: ValueError at /listing/create/

Exception Value: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please, include the whole traceback

Comment: Added full traceback to the original post

Comment: One note, having a comma at the end of `countryList` initialization, makes it a 3d tuple. Try removing it.

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed it, although my form is not rendering now. Any suggestions?